# Result of the $9^{9^9}$

Tags: calculus

So we were given a task for some bonus points to calculate and give the teacher the exact number of $9^{9^9}$. But the number is so big that I couldn't find where to calculate it to receive a precise number. I used python with a gmpy libraby to get a precise number but after almost 4 hours of running it crashed after it ran out of memory. So I am wondering is there actually a way to calculate the precise number?

Comment: Exponentiation is not associative. Please use parenthesis.

Comment: it is easy to write in base 9 :)

Comment: do you want the result by email? it is about 1Gb long

Comment: @NikolayGromov: It's even easier to write down in base $9^{9^9}$.

Comment: What do you want, an explanation about how one might speed up the computation? Or people just throwing digits at you, surely *that* must be your goal...

Comment: Isn't the teacher asking for the number *of decimal digits* of $9^{9^9}$ ? This is a more tractable and instructive question.

Comment: Yes I need decimal result.

Answer (score 3):

Since $9^9 = 387420489$, you have $$\log_{10} 9^{9^9} = 9^9 \log_{10} 9 = 369693099.6\ldots$$
so that the resulting number has 369,693,099 $+$ 1 digits.

Comment: which is less then 1Gb, so assuming 8Gb memory it should be possible to compute it

Comment: @Nikolay: That depends on how you store the digits. But in generally I don't think it's about memory, it's probably about computation time.

Comment: the same objections as some other authors - does not answer the question. It give an impression that the answer is "no way".

Comment: @NikolayGromov feel free to downvote if you don't like the answer.

Comment: @UmbertoP., I generally delete my comments pointing out minor errors once they've been fixed, to remove clutter.  I'll delete this one too once you've had a chance to read it (which you can indicate by deleting your reply).  I had to think about whether the rounding goes up or down.

Answer (score 2):

First $~80$ digits:

$$428124773175747048036987115930563521339055482241443514174753723053523887471735048$$

The rest I can share with dropbox. My estimate - with mathematica it will take about $<7$ days to compute all digits, if you want to try run this:

```
res = 9^9^SetPrecision[9., M]
```

where $M$  is the number of digits. First $10000$ digits take about $4$ minutes.

**Update:**

In Mathematica it take $9$ seconds. The trick to make it faster is to write

```
res = 9^(9^9);
```

that's what Robert Israel did in Maple

**Update2:**

Tried the same order of operations in Python - does not work

```
import gmpy2
a = gmpy2.mpz('9')**gmpy2.mpz('9')
gmpy2.mpz('9')**a
```

crashed kernel in 10 seconds. May be some memory issues.

Comment: Dropbox is no fun. Write it out using paper and ink and send it to the OP's teacher by mail.

Comment: I wonder how many pages it would take at 12-sized times new roman :~)

Comment: About $105000$ for 11-size in Calibri, no ideas about 12

Answer (score 1):

Maple does

```
r := 9^(9^9):
```

in about 10 seconds on my computer.  Outputting the result to a file in Maple's internal format (an m-file) takes about 170 seconds (the file is about 208 Mb).   Saving to a text file (in decimal format) takes about 178 seconds: the file is about 379 Mb.

Comment: Spectacular! Mathematica is much slow in this case which is strate as for such basic operations they both use the same C package for multiple precision algebra.

Comment: In Mathematica that's the same in fact - about $9$ sec.

Answer (score 0):

Well, whatever number you meant $x=(9^9)^9, 9^{9^9}$ you can give your teacher the answer:$x=1$. It is just written in the $x$-ary basis. 
It is impossible for any computer to calculate the second number $x$ in decimal expansion.

**Edit:** Clearly I was wrong regarding the computer power required to perform the calculation!

Comment: are you hinting they are using Python at school?

Comment: Wow, I severely misjudged nowadays computational power. I am not so familiar with computer calculations.

Answer (score -2):

Let $y=9^{9^{9}}$

$\log_{10}(y) = 9^9\log_{10}(9) = 9^{9}\times \times 2 \times 0.4771  = 369676630.6038
$

So $\log_{10}(y) = 369676630.6038\Rightarrow y=10^{369676630.6038}$

Comment: So $9^9^9$ is even?

Comment: No It is odd no. bcz we have take approx of $\log_{10}(3) = 0.4771$

Comment: So your answer is not exact. You might want to make this clear.

Comment: Indeed, the last digit is a 9.

Comment: This does not answer the question, just points out that the number is big. It is not too big, to be honest. It is doable.